# Can I change my PSN name?

Tags: ps4, psn

I'm not all too proud of my PSN ID. Can I change it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sony will not allow you to change your PSN ID. This is to prevent players from griefing others and then changing their name to hide from any consequences.

> "We don't want to make it so that you can go in, grief a bunch of people in Far Cry, change your avatar, change your username, go into CoD and grief everybody over there. We want to stop that."

[Source](http://www.polygon.com/2014/11/15/7225195/PSN-name-change-why-not)